# OpenCV - NoValueError - Tensorflow Object Detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, opencv

Im attempting to build and train a custom model using tensoflow and I want the model to use the webcam of my device but I am getting NoValueErrors from openCV. does anyone know how I would fix them? i have installed open cv on my machine using `pip install opencv-contrib-python --user` and that hasn't changed anything. all files should be correct as I cloned them from official githubs

OpenCV python Code -

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(ANNOTATION_PATH+'/label_map.pbtxt')
cap.release()
# Setup capture
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
while True: 
ret, frame = cap.read()
image_np = np.array(frame)

input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)

num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
              for key, value in detections.items()}
detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

# detection_classes should be ints.
detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

label_id_offset = 1
image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            image_np_with_detections,
            detections['detection_boxes'],
            detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
            detections['detection_scores'],
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            max_boxes_to_draw=5,
            min_score_thresh=.5,
            agnostic_mode=False)

cv2.imshow('object detection',  cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections, (800, 600)))

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    cap.release()
    break
```

and I'm Getting these errors back

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-3a5cc6a8923f> in <module>
      4 
      5     input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
----> 6     detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
      7 
      8     num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    578         xla_context.Exit()
    579     else:
--> 580       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    581 
    582     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    625       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    626       initializers = []
--> 627       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    628     finally:
    629       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    504     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    505         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 506             *args, **kwds))
    507 
    508     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2444       args, kwargs = None, None
   2445     with self._lock:
-> 2446       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2447     return graph_function
   2448 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2775 
   2776       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 2777       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2778       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2779       return graph_function, args, kwargs

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2665             arg_names=arg_names,
   2666             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 2667             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   2668         self._function_attributes,
   2669         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    979         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    980 
--> 981       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    982 
    983       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    439         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    440         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 441         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    442     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    443 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-17-f704d7a53f91>:12 detect_fn  *
        prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(image, shapes)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\meta_architectures\ssd_meta_arch.py:591 predict  *
        predictor_results_dict = self._box_predictor(feature_maps)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\core\box_predictor.py:202 call  *
        return self._predict(image_features, **kwargs)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\predictors\convolutional_keras_box_predictor.py:484 _predict  *
        prediction = head_obj(head_tower_feature)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\predictors\heads\head.py:69 call  *
        return self._predict(features)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\object_detection\predictors\heads\keras_class_head.py:342 _predict  *
        class_predictions_with_background = layer(
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:897 __call__  **
        self._maybe_build(inputs)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:2416 _maybe_build
        self.build(input_shapes)  # pylint:disable=not-callable
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\convolutional.py:1484 build
        dtype=self.dtype)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:577 add_weight
        caching_device=caching_device)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py:724 _add_variable_with_custom_getter
        name=name, shape=shape)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py:791 _preload_simple_restoration
        checkpoint_position=checkpoint_position, shape=shape)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py:75 __init__
        self.wrapped_value.set_shape(shape)
    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:1107 set_shape
        (self.shape, shape))

    ValueError: Tensor's shape (1, 1, 128, 546) is not compatible with supplied shape (1, 1, 128, 18)
```

```
# Load pipeline config and build a detection model
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(CONFIG_PATH)
detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=configs['model'], is_training=False)

# Restore checkpoint
ckpt = tf.compat.v1.train.Checkpoint(model=detection_model)
ckpt.restore(os.path.join(CHECKPOINT_PATH, 'ckpt-0')).expect_partial()

@tf.function
def detect_fn(image):
    image, shapes = detection_model.preprocess(image)
    prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(image, shapes)
    detections = detection_model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)
    return detections
```

Comment: The error is not with the above code, the error occurs at the `detect_fn()`. Could you give the code snippet of the `detect_fn()` ?

Comment: @Kishore i have added it to the question

Comment: The issue is because of the dimension mismatch, I am not sure at which layer the mismatch occurs. Try checking if you are feeding the detection_model the image of shape it expects before feeding into the predict function.

Comment: @Kishore I dont quite understand what you mean?

Comment: What is the CNN model which you are using ?

Comment: CNN model? Do you mean which tensorflow model?

Comment: Try adding `print(image.shape)` before `prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(image, shapes)` and see if that's the shape your model's first layer expects.

Comment: Yes, like mobilenet, alexnet

Comment: im using ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8

Comment: adding the print gave me this (1, 320, 320, 3)